# Add ActionListener to unknown Object

Tags: java, object, parameters, actionlistener

I have the following Problem:

I have a function like this:

```
public void addActionListenerObject(Object object) {
    object.addActionListener(this);
}
```

My problem is the following: I need a solution where I can pass any object with the addActionListener function as a parameter. 
The list can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/eventsandcomponents.html

Is there a way to solve this problem without numerous instances?

Thanks

Comment: what is `this` class definition? extends/implements what classes/interfaces?

Comment: `this` is an ActionListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Keeping Signature**

If you cannot change your method signature (i.e., if you must receive an `Object`, and call `addActionListener()` if there is such a method definition), a more general/robust solution would be using [Java Reflections](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=call%20method%20java%20reflections) to check wether the actual object has an `addActionListener()` method defined, and call it through reflections as well. Sounds a very hacky approach, anyway.

**Changing Signature**

If you can change your method signature, try using `AbstractButton` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)), which is the superclass that defines this method for `JButton`, `JToggleButton` and `JMenuItem`, for instance (see "Direct Known Subclasses" and the class definition tree to find out where the methods are actually provided).

This second approach will work only if there is actually a single superclass defining the method. If there is more than one, you'll have to check for the possible classes using `if-else` structure and `instanceof` + explicit cast (than you can keep your original `Object` signature).

If you give more information on your original problem (like, why do you need such a method), we'll probably be able to find better approaches.

Comment: So the approach with the AbstractButton is one I did already, but it doesn't cover up the other objects. The Reflection Method is probably the best one, but the Performance could be a problem. I need the method to wrap multiple Action Listeners into one Libary by me... To be honest, I just could the user add my Object as ActionListener, but It doesn't feel right. The if-else structure is probably the best approach...

Comment: The reflection method is more robust, as any third party or future classes that implement `addActionListener(...)` method will work with no code change. In the other hand, if the probability of needing the method to be so robust is low (meaning that probable use will be with a close set of classes, including AbstractButton, etc), and performance and code maintainability are more important requirements, I'd choose the `if-else` approach. As always, the best choice will depend on the whole picture of your actual problem. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Pass a functional interface (>= Java 1.8 only) if you are allowed to change the signature of `addActionListenerObject`:

```
public class Just {
    private ActionListener actionListener;
    public void addActionListener(ActionListener actionListener) {
        this.actionListener = actionListener;
    }
    public void doIt() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        actionListener.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, 3, "World"));
    }
}

public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void addActionListenerObject(Consumer<ActionListener> consumer) {
        consumer.accept(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
    }
}
```

That way, the classes that add the action listener (in my example this is `Just`) need not to implement an interface.

Use it:

```
Just just = new Just();

MyActionListener listener = new MyActionListener();
listener.addActionListenerObject(just::addActionListener); // Aha!

just.doIt();
```

This prints:

```
Hello
World
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>What you're looking for is polymorphism. All instances of type `Component` have the `addActionListener` method. Change your method signature to expect a `Component`, not an `Object`.</s>

I thought `addActioListener` was inherited from `Component`. It is not.
The method is individually added to each component type, with no parent class.

Comment: The Class Component doesn't have the function addActionListener. I had the same Idea, but I am searching the right class and I am unable to find it.

Comment: See my edit. Your best bet is to write individual methods for each type necessary.